# Groupby, shif and rolling mean in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to groupby, shift and do a rolling mean in pandas. I have searched for solutions but without luck. I have a workaround, but it's not the best. Especially since I need to do rolling standard deviations in future. Could anyone help me and suggest a better way to do this?

Input data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'month': [201912, 202001, 202001, 202002, 202002, 202003, 202003, 202004],
               'target': [0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1]
              },
              index = [14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21])
```

Expected output for a 2-month rolling mean and shift of one month:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'month': [201912, 202001, 202002, 202003, 202004],
               'roll_2m': [np.nan, np.nan, 0.33, 0.75, 0.5]
              },
              index = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
```

A bad workaround to solve this is something like:

```
rolling_count = df.shift(1).target['count'].rolling(2).sum()
rolling_sum = df.shift(1).target['sum'].rolling(2).sum()
rolling_mean = rolling_sum/rolling_count                           
df['roll_2m'] = rolling_mean
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would first do a `groupby().agg()`:

```
(df.groupby('month').target.agg(['sum','count'])
   .rolling(2)
   .sum().shift()
   .assign(roll_2m=lambda x: x['sum']/x['count'])
)
```

Output:

```
        sum  count   roll_2m
month                       
201912  NaN    NaN       NaN
202001  NaN    NaN       NaN
202002  1.0    3.0  0.333333
202003  3.0    4.0  0.750000
202004  2.0    4.0  0.500000
```

Comment: Thanks, I think it's a better solution